# How to call static method with data binding?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-databinding

I want to call my Util class method in `layout.xml` file like

```
<TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@{PreferenceUtil.getSavedUser().fullName}"/>
```

I have imported `PreferenceUtil`

```
<import type="com.amelio.utils.PreferenceUtil"/>
```

And `PreferenceUtil.class` has some methods.

```
public class PreferenceUtil {

    public static LoginResponse getSavedUser() {
        SharedPreferences sf = Amelio.getInstance().getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String userJson = sf.getString(PREF_USER_DATA, null);
        if (userJson == null || userJson.equals("")) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Gson().fromJson(userJson, LoginResponse.class);
    }
}
```

**Issue**

```
    Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method getSavedUser() in class com.amelio.utils.PreferenceUtil
file:D:\Khemraj\_AndroidStudioWorkspace_\amelioFinal\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_cart.xml
loc:94:40 - 94:68
****\ data binding error ****
```

**Is this even possible, also suggest if this is recommended or not.**

Comment: Calling static methods from data binding expressions definitely works -- I use `Html.fromHtml()` in various book examples. Is `LoginResponse` marked as `public`? Also, **please** do not do I/O (`getSharedPreferences()`) and data parsing (`new Gson().fromJson()`) on the main application thread, as you are here.

Comment: Why does it say `can not find getSavedUser`

Comment: For example, if `LoginResponse` is not `public`, it is possible that the data binding framework cannot really resolve that method reference.

Comment: @CommonsWare Am I able to access getSavedUser() from layout file if PreferenceUtil is a final class and not publicly instantiable. I mean the class is public and getSavedUser() method is public and static

Comment: @user3135923: Use an `<import>` element in the `<data>` to declare the `PreferenceUtil` type, using the fully-qualified class name. Then, your binding expressions can refer to the static methods on that class.

Answer (score 7):

I hope you must have found the answer in case if you are still struggling then find the answer below.

```
    <data>
      <import type="com.amelio.utils.PreferenceUtil"/>
 </data>


<TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text='@{PreferenceUtil.getSavedUser()}' />
```

Please make sure your LoginResponse is marked public to access the values.

Answer (score 1):

in case you haven't found the answer yet:

you need to import the object type and cast it to that type  like this:

```
<data>
  <import type="com.amelio.utils.PreferenceUtil"/>
  <import type="yourdirectory.LoginResponse"/>

</data>


<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text='@{((LoginResponse)(PreferenceUtil.getSavedUser()).fullName}' />
```